# node.js + post request

Tags: node.js, http-post

I am trying to call post data method of another application(which is running in localhost:3000) using node.js. But its returning error..

The following is the code:

```
var options = {
  host: 'localhost',
  path: '/v1/key/11111111',
  //since we are listening on a custom port, we need to specify it by hand
  port: '3000',
  //This is what changes the request to a POST request
  method: 'POST',  
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
};

callback = function(response) {
  var str = ''
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });

  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log(str);
  });
}

var req = http.request(options, callback);
//This is the data we are posting, it needs to be a string or a buffer
req.write("hello world!");
req.end();
```

But i am receiving error:

```
{"meta":{"version":1,"status_code":400},"results":{"error":{"type":"Error","message":"invalid json"}}}
```

When i am trying using `CURL` command i am getting the desired result:

```
curl -X POST  localhost:3000/v1/key/12345678 --header "Content-Type:application/json"
```

My question is how i have to construct `POST request for the above requirement`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specify 'application/json' in the request options. But you provide the string "Hello world!", which is not json, and that's what the error message tells you.

Try changing the header or the content.

Comment: Thanks.I want to sent empty json {} , what i have to do.. i tried req.write({}). i am receiving error throw new TypeError('first argument must be a string or Buffer');

Comment: You need to send valid json as a string, try this: req.write("{}");